# Installing RWeka XMeans behind proxy

Tags: r

**Short question: where is the zip-file of XMeans package for RWeka?**

I was able to install RWeka, but in order to install XMeans I need to use their package manager (WPM). 
I could use WPM("install-package","XMeans") which works when Im off the network.. but that won't do 'on' (my work) network.

From the description it says that instead of "XMeans" I could also provide an url or zip-file. Do you guys know where this zip-file (or something similar) of the XMeans package is located?

Comment: have you solved your issue?

Comment: @Seymour sadly, no...